# Restructuring json data to remove blank spaces from an Ag-grid table

Tags: reactjs, json, key-value

I have 4 fields in my json data and i am displaying it using Ag-grid. i need to dynamically restructure my data to remove the blank spaces in my Ag-grid table considering that there could be n number of rows to randomData.i am using reactjs in my code and below is my json data

```
const randomData = [
  { a: '1',y: 10 },
  { a: '2',y: 20 },
  { b: '3',z: 30 },
  { b: '4',z: 40 },
  { b: '5',z: 50 }]
<AgGridReact
        rowData={randomData}
        columnDefs={columns}
      />
```

**Current output**
[image: Current output]

I want to dynamically re-structure data of my json to obtain

**Desired output**
[image: Desired output]

I tried a couple of methods using reduce() and map(). but i wasnt able to solve my issue.

Comment: do you kow the output of what the data array would look like?

Comment: yes
const data = [
  { a: '1',y: 10 ,b: '3',z: 30 },
  { a: '2',y: 20 ,b: '4',z: 40 },
  {b: '5',z: 50 },
];

Comment: whats the link?  meaning, how is row { a: '1',y: 10 } related too { b: '3',z: 30 }

Comment: hey, thankyou for trying to help me out. I am new to coding and i just found a way to get the desired output by manually restructuring the data. basically a-y can have multiple values and is not dependent on the number of values b-z  can have.

Comment: ok yeah it looked like the data needed  restructuring.  I will post an answer for posterity consider accepting it to close the loop

Answer (score 0):

There doesnt seem to be a link in the data to allow that output.  For example the first row of { a: '1',y: 10 } does not have a relation to { b: '3',z: 30 }.  The input data needs to be restructured so that there is a key/link/relation from a/y to b/z.